# Caliburn Micro active multiple user control in one page

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, screen, caliburn.micro

I am new in caliburn microframework and MVVM itself in WPF. I am looking for way how to achieve activating multiple user control in one page, dependent on user selection.

As you can see in the picture below, when user clicks on the new file the window "Select calculation" will appear and in the checkboxes user can select calculation according some standards like DIN, CSN etc.

After confirmation with OK button, in the "Input parameters screen part" then appear User controls which will contain textboxes for input parameters.

Problem is that every standard has slightly different parameters for calculation. So my goal is to open only user control with input parameters textboxes and labels which are corresponding with selected standard.

So my question is: How to achieve this activating of multiple user controls in one screen part? If I use conductor I can activate only one item in time.

I thought about approach that I will load all input parameters user controls and make visible only these which corresponding with standards that user selected.

[Image representing layout of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQxee.png)

Comment: Conductor<object>.Collection.AllActive here is a demo view change git of mine.https://github.com/juanvan/ViewChangerAsync

Comment: Thank you for answer! It helped me to deeper understand how container registering per request works.